# vsix multi template project creates an extra folder

Tags: templates, vsix, multi-project

I am trying to create a multi project template (.vsix) file.  One of the projects has a reference to two nuget packages.  Everything works fine except for the part where the project itself gets created.  It creates an additional folder under the root folder.  So if I call my project "Prj1" it will create the sub projects under Prj1 -> Prj1 -> Sub Projects.  I dont want it to do this, and as a result of this the package references and everything does not work.  I tried searching the web for a solution and all I found is this
[Issue with visual studio template & directory creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882764/issue-with-visual-studio-template-directory-creation)

But here also I am not sure if this solves the problem based on the comments.  Is there any standard fix for this?

Comment: I've experienced the same problem and I gave up. I believe the only chance is trying that solution.